# How to add spaces instead of null in StringBuilder when setting length?

Tags: java, stringbuilder

I use `var.setLength(8);` so it appears as "55[THERE ARE 6x NULL]". 
How can I replace it easily instead of iterating over all String and replacing it with spaces. Or can I Override setLength method to append spaces instead of nulls?

Comment: So you want to pad the string to a certain length, without explicitly writing a loop? You do realise that there _is_ going to be a loop somewhere (just not necessarily written by you), right?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Padding a stringbuilder with spaces? Is this performance critical code or are you required to use a stringbuilder?

Comment: Yea, it's good idea to use String with String.format instead of StringBuilder, I just thought it would be more readable code with it.

Answer (score 1):

The StringBuilder.setLength() call is not for adding characters, but adding space for characters.

Take a look at String.repeat() that came with Java 11.

Comment: Would be nice if you flagged this response as a valid answer :)